# Can't integrate SWT with JavaFX under "Zulu" JDK 11

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, swt, java-module

We want to use both SWT and JavaFX in an Eclipse plugin within our RCP application. Unfortunately, we're experiencing problems integrating SWT with JavaFX under Java 11. The build environment uses e(fx)clipse 3.5. We're developing against the Community edition of Azul Systems' "Zulu" JDK 11, bundled with Azul's version of OpenJFX.

Formerly, we developed under Java 8. At that point, our build used a compile-time class path referring to `jfxswt.jar`, which lived in the `jre/lib` directory of the JDK. We didn't use any special class path settings at run-time.

We are now trying to move to Java 11. There, this JAR has become `javafx-swt.jar` and lives in the `lib` directory of the JDK. It no longer seems to be enough to set the class path to refer to this JAR at compile time: it seems to be necessary to do so at run time too. If we don't do this, we get an error (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas`).

As a test, we experimentally embedded `javafx-swt.jar` within the JAR implementing our Eclipse plugin. We then referred to it in that plugin's `.classpath` file, and the code worked as expected. Unfortunately, we can't embed the JAR this way for legal and other reasons.

A note on Java modules: `javafx.swt` does not show up in the output when we issue the `--list-module` command. We tried running the application using parameters `-p /path/to/JDK/lib/javafx-swt.jar --add-modules javafx.swt`, but this doesn't seem to solve the problem.

My question: Is there a way to set up the class or module path to allow our Eclipse plugin to find this library in the JRE? Any solution would have to work with whatever JRE the code happens to be run against (I think it is all right to assume `lib/javafx-swt.jar` will live in that JRE).

Would it help to use a separately-downloaded version of OpenJFX rather than the copy of OpenJFX in our JDK?

Very many thanks ☺

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but apparently `javafx.swt` is an _automatic_ module (i.e. there's no `module-info` file).

Comment: You’re doing something very wrong.  JavaFX is part of Java SE in Java 8, so you should not be adding *any* .jar files to your classpath.  Entries in a module path should be *directories containing modules,* not individual .jar files, for example `-p /opt/javafx/lib`.  Even if you were referring to .jar files, you should be referring to actual public modules like javafx.controls.jar and never javafx-swt.jar.